# Python Project only taking env variables that were initialized at the very start

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, dotenv

I am trying to use some variables using:

**settings.py**

```
from dotenv import dotenv_values
config = dotenv_values("/etc/env/env_file")
```

**Content of env_file:**

```
TOP_MAX = 12
KEY = value
```

It works fine at first, loading all the variables but after changing the content of the env file while the project is running, the functions using this variables are still using the old values. I get that after the project has started Python gets values from a cached variable, but I am looking for any workaround if any to load the current values of the env file in the function after it is modified while running. Sorry for the sloppy terminologies

Comment: that is not how it would work, that kind of "hot-reloading" isn't supported by default. You'll have to either re-fire the command : `config = dotenv_values("/etc/env/env_file")`  periodically, or try some other library.

Comment: Yeah, I know that is not supported by default and that's why asking if there is any known workaround for this because we can't restart the project whenever we need to change any variable, so is there any known and trusted library for the same?

Comment: I also can't set a particular period to run the command, as the function using this can be called anytime

Comment: is it possible to just use simple python decorators for the same? just annonate your method with `@latest_props` and the decorator will run the update for you?

Comment: Sorry but can you please elaborate, not entirely sure about what you are implying

Comment: jump straight to : @hello_decorator using Ctrl + F in this page : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-in-python/

Comment: okayy, thanks a lot, will try this

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment such as venv? If so then you will need to restart that environment to load the changes back in as env vars.

Answer (score 3):

One way to get around and load the env variables as well as access them you can use the following approach:

```py
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv(verbose=True, override=True)

print(os.environ["DATABASE_URI"])
```

This will override the cached values and you can access the new .env values everytime you run the script

Answer (score 1):

To complement @Cephalo's answer, you can also specify the .env path explicitly:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

# Load the .env file using find_dotenv(), which searches for the .env file starting from the current directory
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=find_dotenv(),  # Or BASE_DIR/'.env',
            verbose=True,               # Print verbose output for debugging purposes
            override=True)              # Override system environment variables with values from .env

# By using override=True, the system environment variables will be overridden by the values from the .env file
# This ensures that you access the latest values from the .env file every time you run the script
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it super compatible with how it is being configured at the begining of the script, you can define a class that has a `__getitem__` method (so it behaves exactly like your config dictionary), but that reloads the variables at each call:

```py
class Config():
    def __init__(self, env_path):
        self.path = env_path
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        _conf = dotenv.dotenv_values(self.path)

        return _conf.get(key, None)
```

I tested that this updates the variable values while the script is running using this script and editing the `.env` file while it was going:

```py
import time
import dotenv


class Config():
    def __init__(self, env_path):
        self.path = env_path
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        _conf = dotenv.dotenv_values(self.path)

        return _conf.get(key, None)


def main():
    config = Config(".env")

    while True:
        print("TOP_MAX", config["TOP_MAX"])
        print("KEY", config["KEY"])
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

where you can also see the same interaction with `config` as you would have in the original setting